# THREE.JS - Glitched lines at two face's intersection

Tags: javascript, three.js, intersection, voxel, visual-glitch

I am currently working on a voxel Minecraft like JavaScript game to improve my JS/TS skills but i am facing an issue.

I draw my voxels by drawing multiple faces of blocks in a BufferGeometry but, between two faces, there is a glitched line like in this image.
[image: glitch]

Here are some parts of my code that could be usefull to understand where the problem come from:

My material:

```
const texture = loader.load(this.instance.ressourceMapUrl);
texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
const material = this.blockMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: texture,
    alphaTest: 0.1,
    transparent: true,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});
```

My BufferGeometry:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const positionNumComponents = 3;
geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), positionNumComponents));
const normalNumComponents = 3;
geometry.setAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(normals), normalNumComponents));
const uvNumComponents = 2;
geometry.setAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(uvs), uvNumComponents));
geometry.setIndex(indices);
        
geometry.colors = new Float32Array(colors);
geometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( geometry.colors, 3, true) );

geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

A little sample of the vertexes of a normal chunk:

```
[0, 12, 0, 0, 12, 1, 1, 12, 0, 1, 12, 1, 1, 12, 0, 1, 12, 1, 2, 12, 0, 2, 12, 1, 2, 12, 0, 2, 12, 1, 3, 12, 0, 3, 12, 1, 3, 12, 0, 3, 12, 1, 4, 12, 0, 4, 12, 1, 4, 12, 0, 4, 12, 1, 5, 12, 0, 5, 12...]
```

Vertexes are used in this order:

```
let ndx = positions.length/3;
indices.push(
    ndx, ndx + 1, ndx + 2,
    ndx + 2, ndx + 1, ndx + 3,
);
```

My far & near variables:

```
    const near = 0.101;
    const far = 240
```

Thank you a lot for reading this, I know it may be an idiot question but I'm struggling on that for a week and can't manage to find any solution on the web.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Your image is really dark. Please consider updating it with a brighter one. Also, please embed the image in your post (use the "Image <img>" button in the edit toolbar). That will ensure the image stays available on Stack Overflow, even if the imgur link goes away.

Comment: Might be `alphaTest: 0.1`. Why do you need that line? Also, what is your camera's `near` and `far` properties? It might be a z-depth precision issue if your `far` plane is *realllly* far... maybe. Or third, why are you building your own vertices from scratch? Have you tried just using the built-in [`BoxBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/BoxBufferGeometry)?

Comment: Thank you for responding !
I can't embed image for now, since I don't have 10 reputation points but I updated the image to a better one.
I need the alphaTest line because it ensure that if a box has a transparent texture, boxes behind are still being rendered by ThreeJS.
I updated the original post with my far & near distance (near: 0.101 & far = 240)

I don't use BoxBufferGeometry because I try to optimize the game the most and I need to process culling etc myself in order to have the best performance possible.

Comment: Like Marquizzo said, it _looks like_ a z-fighting issue, but your depth is rather short, so I'm thinking not.

Comment: I suppose this could be a simple mathematical hiccup caused by a rounding error in JavaScript. This could come from if you're positioning your blocks base on floats, and those floats are calculated. (Empirical personal experience says you can't trust more than a `1e-6` precision from JS.)

Comment: OR this could be a texture problem--you may need to try a different kind of filter to ensure the edges "snap" for every fragment.

Comment: Finally, I see lots of jaggies in your scene. Enable anti-aliasing for your renderer. It's not going to affect the "blocky-ness" of your blocks, it will just smooth out the edges, which may resolve the artifacts you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, the problem was coming from my textures. Thank you a lot TheJim01 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and how to solve it :
This was coming from my textures. Since floats are not precise, it was making these lines.

In order to fix this, I moved the corners I used for my texture by 0.0001 to the center.

The coordinates of my textures from my texture map are stored like this : [x1, y1 x2, y2].
I did this:

```
let uv: [number, number, number, number] = ...;
let correction = uv[0] > uv[2] ? 0.0001 : -0.0001;
uv[0] -= correction;
uv[2] += correction;
correction = uv[1] > uv[3] ? 0.0001 : -0.0001;
uv[1] -= correction;
uv[3] += correction;
```

Thank you to everyone that tried to help me and I hope it can help some other people as well !